# QGIS Python Console AddMaplayer but with low resolution (very dim)

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, pyqt

### Update： Figured. I used the wrong style file.

I'm new to QGIS Python develop. I was trying to add raster layer (.asc file) into QGIS. Below are my srcrips.

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
import gdal
import os

filePath = "path/2017011003.asc"
style_layer = "path/StreamStyle.qml"

fileInfo = QFileInfo(filePath)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(filePath, baseName)
if not rlayer.isValid():
  print "Layer failed to load!"

crs = rlayer.crs()
crs.createFromId(4610,QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
rlayer.setCrs(crs)

rlayer.loadNamedStyle(style_layer)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

I did add the raster layer into qgis, but the problem is that the layer seems very dim... I also import the same raster image by just using the qgis "Add Raster Layer" function which shows quite clear

Here is the comparison:

added by scripts (dim)

[image: added by scripts (dim)]

[image: added by using QGIS "Add Raster Layer" function]

added by using QGIS "Add Raster Layer" function

Comment: Does it look the same if you use `rlayer.triggerRepaint()`?

Comment: Thank you. I figured the problem... It was due to the style file. I didn't use the new version. (Though I didn't figure out the giant difference between two style files.) Anyway, the new version of style file works well now.

Comment: Ahh nice one! Normally you should post the solution as an **answer** but as your problem is not really reproducable, it may get flagged =)